# Arabic font issue in windows form application using C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows

I am using resource file for Arabic Conversion in Windows form...It's all are working Perfectly but Problem with Buttons and Form Text not showing Proper letter........instead of that it showing small small box

Arabic Character not comming Properly

Comment: A small rectangle means that the operating system doesn't have a font that can display the character.  That could be because it doesn't have a font available that can display Arabic glyphs.  Or it could mean that you not converting text properly, fairly unlikely if you use resources properly.  Pretty important that you test localization on an Arabic version of Windows.  Which of course always has the required font.

Comment: But Sir Arabic text displaying in Label , It is not displaying for Buttons and Form Text.......

Answer (score 0):

This will be an encoding issue, you will have to set your encodings to UTF8 as the standard ASCII encoding does not support Arabic characters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbx3z216(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How to set encoding ?

Comment: I'll need some more information on how you created and saved your resource file and how you are setting your text from the resource file onto the control.

Comment: Cultureinfo ci=new Cultureinfo("ar-AE")

Comment: Also don't forget CurrentUICulture

Answer (score 0):

Go to control panel->Religon n language setting->language->check the first script checkbox->install the script by using xp cd